# Mangoldt function and sigma $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory

Is there any way to express this explisit instead of using sigma?
$$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}$$
Mangoldt function: $\Lambda(x)=\begin{cases}\ln p,&\text{if $x=p^k$}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Perhaps it would be possible to use the chebyshev function: $\psi(x)=\sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)$?

Comment: Mertens's theorem says that your sum is asympotic to $\log m$, and the prime number theorem implies that it equals $\log m - \gamma$ up to an error term that tends to $0$ (where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant). One can write an exact "explicit formula" for the sum involving the zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 1):

By summation by parts
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n} = \frac{\psi(N)}{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{\psi(n)}{n(n+1)}$$
and since $\psi(n)\sim n$ by the PNT, the LHS is expected to behave like $\log(N)+O(1)$.